# http-proxy-middleware does not forward the full path

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, http-proxy, browser-sync

I am trying to configure BrowserSync to work in server mode and to proxy my API requests to the backend that runs on the same machine on a different port, using [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware). I use Gulp to launch BrowserSync.

BrowserSync runs on port 8081. My backend runs on 8080.

Here is how I create the proxy middleware :

```
var proxyApi = proxy('/api', {target : 'http://localhost:8080/api', logLevel : 'debug'});
```

And here is how I run BrowserSync from my Gulp task :

```
// Init BrowserSync with proxies as middleware and based on the dest dir
browserSync.init({
    open: true,
    port: config.proxyPort,
    server: {
        baseDir: config.destDir,
        middleware: [proxyApi]
    },
    browser: "google chrome"
});
```

The output :

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://localhost:8080/api
```

Everything looks good.

But When I hit e.g. `http://localhost:8081/api/users`, the output is :

```
[HPM] GET /api/users/123 -> http://localhost:8080/api
```

...And my client gets a 404 error because `/api` on its own does not match anything on the backend.

From what I understood from the doc and examples, the target should actually be `http://localhost:8080/api/users/123`

Why is the rest of the path (in this case `/users/123`) being left out ?

Using the following versions :

```
"gulp": "3.9.1",
"browser-sync": "2.16.0",
"http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.1",
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `prependPath` option is `true` by default. This option is provided by the underlying lib: [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).

> **prependPath**: true/false, Default: **true** - specify whether you want to
>   prepend the target's path to the proxy path

There are two ways to fix the issue:

1.) Change your `target` from `'http://localhost:8080/api'` to `'http://localhost:8080'`

```
var proxyApi = proxy('/api', {target: 'http://localhost:8080', logLevel: 'debug'});
```

2.) Alternatively you can set the option `prependPath` to `false`.

```
var proxyApi = proxy('/api', {target: 'http://localhost:8080/api', prependPath: false, logLevel: 'debug'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the solutions. The second one works well for me since I only want to proxy certain routes and not the whole server. I must say that the name of the `prependPath` parameter is not very intuitive for what it does.

Comment: There is no real difference between option 1 and 2 apart from difference in configuration. The first argument `'/api'` is making sure only those request are proxied. Can't think of why you would keep the target+path: `http://localhost:8080/api` and the extra `prependPath` option if it is counter-intuitive. :)